# Counting cartesian product of 3+ sets without duplicates

Tags: combinatorics

I have three sets A, B and C, and want to find the number of ordered combinations of elements a, b and c, but eliminating all tuples where an element is repeated in two or more positions in a tuple. In other words, taking the cartesian product, filtering the result, then counting the members in the set:

$$\bigg|\{ (a,b,c)\, :\, a \in A,\ b \in B,\ c \in C, a \not= b, a\not= c, b \not= c \}\bigg|$$

At present I have written an algorithm to solve this, but is there a simpler way to solve this problem in terms of set operations (intersection, union etc), rather than exhaustively testing all combinations of a, b and c?

And as a followup question, if there is a simpler solution, is there a form of the solution for 4 sets or more?

Comment: hmm...how about $(a,b,c) : a \in A,\ b \in B$ \{$a$}$,\ c \in C$ \{ $a,b$}

Comment: Daniel, I suppose that's equivalent, but is there an equation involving the cardinality of the union or intersection of the sets A, B and C that I can use to determine the cardinality of the filtered set of tuples?